# About Jake's fate in The Gunslinger

Tags: stephen-king, the-dark-tower-king

I've just finished reading *The Gunslinger* and I'm really sad about Jake and how Roland left him behind. I want to know at least if in the other books of the series there will be some mention that Jake is okay and nothing happened to him, that he has forgiven Roland or anything like that. Or maybe Roland will get redemption, later on? I want to know if he will feel guilty and try to redeem himself somehow.

**Please try to not spoil anything from the next books as much as possible. I'm fine with something not major or critical.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual situation that Jake ends up in after Roland left him behind is...a little odd, primarily because of other events later in book 2, *The Drawing of the Three*. It's not exactly like "nothing happened to him". But without spoiling too much, rest assured that **Jake will make a comeback to the *Dark Tower* series**, specifically in book 3 *The Waste Lands*, and from then on stays a major character throughout the whole story.

The events of *The Gunslinger*, specifically Roland leaving him behind, will however still remain to **stand between Jake and Roland for quite some time**, though, even if more on a deeper emotional level and less as a direct conflict. It's not like he just forgives him right away. But you will notice that Roland doesn't always show himself from his best side in his quest for the Tower, yet his companions largely manage to deal with it and stay with him nevertheless. He is to a large degree a bit of an anti-hero.

However, Roland's actions don't go without effect on *him* either and he *does* feel guilty about what he did to Jake. But ***remorse* on the other hand is a different question, since Roland is also a very stubborn character** and he is convinced that the things he does to reach the Tower, how bad they might be, are *necessary*, since the quest for the Tower is everything for him.

With regards to Roland's redemption, that's...a bit of an overarching theme throughout the entire series, so I'd hesitate to delve too much into details. But Roland will to some degree make a development in his character and realize the errors in some of his ways, specifically also in his relationship to Jake. **The two will also ultimately make peace about what Roland did.**

This is all a little vague, but if you **keep reading, all your concerns will be adressed significantly**.

Comment: that's a great answer and what I was looking for exactly, thanks very much!